# How to change type of output control flow in synapse pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

From my understanding, in Azure Synapse pipelines, if you have two blocks that both have their output arrows pointing to the same block, that block will wait for both to finish.
For example, say I have the following dummy pipeline:

[image]

And here is some of the code syntax for that Process_Error block, regarding the dependencies (arrows):

```
"dependsOn": [
        {
            "activity": "Cause_Error",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Failed"
            ]
        },
        {
            "activity": "No_Error",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Failed"
            ]
        },
        {
            "activity": "No_Error_v2",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Failed"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

In this test example, I have a notebook, called "No_Error", that does nothing notable, but finishes execution normally.  And another one, called "Cause_Error", that intentionally raises an exception, so it should never finish normally.

The idea being: In a real pipeline, if there are no errors, I would like to continue to execute through the entire pipeline.  However, if there is a failure in any given block, I would like it to move to a block that handles and logs errors, then ends the execution of the pipeline.

If I don't want to duplicate the error process block for each block that could result in an error, I thought to just have them all point to the same block.  Though, since blocks require all incoming output streams to complete before executing, it will never execute this process error block (since it expects an 'on failure' from two different blocks, but will only ever get it from one of them)

This dummy example symbolizes that this approach won't be able to work with the simple 'and' checking for the outputs.  Since the first No_Error will not produce an 'on failure' output, and the second No_Error will never even be executed since it only starts if the one before it exits normally, which it will not in this case (so it will not have an 'on failure' output either).

Is there some way to make the 'or' behavior arrows, or is there some other approach I am not thinking of (other than simply having a process error block for each of the normal execution blocks)?  I have a feeling I am overlooking something very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the above scenario with set variable activities, and I got the same result.

[image]

In the above all are set variable activities.

In Synapse or ADF, the pipeline flow is designed such that it will execute the activities which has received all inputs from its previous activities.
In the above the last activity won't execute because it is not receiving green signal from its previous activities.

> The idea being: In a real pipeline, if there are no errors, I would
> like to continue to execute through the entire pipeline. However, if
> there is a failure in any given block, I would like it to move to a
> block that handles and logs errors, then ends the execution of the
> pipeline.

You can use **Execute pipeline** activity for this scenario. Execute pipeline activity is used for running a pipeline from another pipeline.

first create another pipeline and drag Execute pipeline activity from the menu.
Then select child pipeline from the drop down. **Here child pipeline is your main pipeline.**

[image]

In this pipeline create your **block to handle and log the errors**. Here I have used a set variable activity for sample.

Join the Failure of Execute pipeline to your block like above.

Every pipeline stops execution on first failed activity. In this also ***your main pipeline execution will be stopped on first failed block*** and returns to parent pipeline. The ***Execute pipeline will give you the same error of failed activity*** which you can handle and log in your block later.

If your main pipeline results success, then Execute pipeline also returns success.

[image]

You can see the error of **set variable activity**(named as **failure**) in the Execute pipeline.

You can use the below expression to get this **Error JSON** in your next block.

```
@activity('Execute pipeline1').error
```